# How to perform Content Negotiation when the Accept header is not present

Tags: rest, http, rss, atom-feed, web-standards

I've been working on a [standards-based application framework called Maki](https://github.com/martindale/maki), which aims to isolate "resources" on the web to a single URL.  However, I've found that many HTTP clients don't provide ample information, particularly in the context of [Content Negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation).

For example, [a podcast hosted using this framework](https://decentralize.fm/) expects the "Shows" collection to be provided at `/shows`, and it will respond with the appropriately formatted content based on the incoming request.  For example, [accessing the page with a web browser](https://decentralize.fm/shows) renders an HTML listing of the episodes, while the same URL will return an Atom feed when the client specifies it wants XML:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/xml" https://decentralize.fm/shows
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <channel>
  ...
  </channel>
</rss>
```

However, I've noticed that the headers on many (most!) HTTP clients, including iTunes, do not send an `Accept` header, in this particular case to expect an XML response.  Why is that?

Other than serving a new URL to provide an XML-formatted version of the same resource, what alternatives exist to determine how to format the response?

Answer (score 1):

The core concept I would build from, the focus of my point of view, is the maxim "know your audience."  Your base response (your result of last resort) should be the content that your primary audience expects, regardless of what you want to deliver.  So if the largest group of people hitting this URL are itunes clients, you need to serve itunes-friendly formatting.  Remember that your primary audience dictates what you should be delivering, and not the other way around.  You don't really get the luxury of choosing who your audience is.  You can only put your content out there and conform to what they want.

Secondly you can/should use the Accept header like you wanted.  And of course there's the extra old school crude method of browser detection via user agent. The other thing to take into consideration is that if you're trying to serve multiple content types to the same client based on accept headers then you're actually breaking client caching, because caching is dictated by the URL.